# How to access inner objects in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, el, thymeleaf

I am trying to Iterate a List if `User`s using thymeleaf,

My `User` object is like this

```
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer userId;
    private Department department;
    private String email;
    // setters and getters etc
}
```

and department object is like this

```
public class Department implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer departmentId;
    private String name;
    // setters and getters etc
}
```

in thymeleaf I do this

```
<tr th:each="user : ${users}">
    <td th:text="${user.email}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.department.name}"></td>
</tr>
```

and I am getting this error

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "user.department.name"
```

if I use only `user.email`, there is no issues.

So how to access inner objects in in Thymeleaf EL? (In my case `user.department.name`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are accessing it correctly, but you will get an exception if the department on the user is null.

What you can do is use null safe dereferencing using the '?' operator, i.e.

```
<td th:text="${user.department?.name}"></td>
```

This will check first whether department is null. See Spring EL's [Safe Navigation Operator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-operator-safe-navigation)

Comment: thanks for the input , I'll check and update. I think there is some issue in the Department class(If this syntax is ok).

Comment: The issue was in my Query, Department had a fetch type LAZY , so I have to use FETCH in Query.I'll accept the answer as department was null when accessed from thymeleaf.